# How to alter these functions so that they recursively find the solution

Tags: python, functional-programming

This is a question about Project Euler problem #67. (Find the maximum path down a triangle) I know it may be in bad taste to ask for help on these.

I have these functions:

```
def chooseBest(rowOfTriangle):
    if len(rowOfTriangle) == 1:
        return rowOfTriangle
    return list(max(element) for element in zip(rowOfTriangle[0:-1],rowOfTriangle[1:]))
```

and:

```
def consolidatePath(rowOfTriangle , bestPath):
    return list(sum(element) for element in zip(rowOfTriangle,bestPath))
```

which work on a data set formatted like this:

```
triangle = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

where the solution for this triangle would look like:

```
consolidatePath(triangle[0],chooseBest(consolidatePath(triangle[1],chooseBest(consolidatePath(triangle[2],chooseBest(triangle[3]))))))
```

This outputs (correctly):

```
[20]
```

Writing out each nested function call is far from optimal, and is going to be impossible when I scale up to the problem's hundred rows. How do I alter `consolidatePath` and `chooseBest` to call each other where appropriate?

EDIT:
Figured it out.

Comment: If you figured it out, then post the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def max_path(triangle, idx=0, total=0):
    if triangle:
        row = triangle[0]
        next = max(row[idx:idx+2])
        return max_path(triangle[1:], row.index(next), total+next)
    return total
```

Comment: While your method finds the sum of the largest elements in each row, it's not guaranteed to find the `max_path` like the method suggests. (swap 2 & 3 in the second row in the given test data and the max path is 19 but this would still return 20).

Comment: Ah good point, I guess I didn't understand the problem very well.